# Storybook does not seem to be working on node 10.15.3

Tags: node.js, storybook

I install storybook on my machine and when I run (without making any change) this is the error I get:

```
> POCs@1.0.0 storybook D:\Work\projects\POCs
> start-storybook -p 6006

info @storybook/react v5.3.11
info
info => Loading presets
info => Loading presets
info => Adding stories defined in ".storybook\main.js".
info => Using default Webpack setup.
D:\Work\projects\POCs\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\dev-server.js:80
          stats.toJson(options.errorDetails);
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJson' of null
    at Watching.watch [as handler] (D:\Work\projects\POCs\node_modules\@storybook\core\dist\server\dev-server.js:80:17)
    at Watching._done (D:\Work\projects\POCs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:95:9)
    at onCompiled (D:\Work\projects\POCs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:44:26)
    at hooks.beforeCompile.callAsync.err (D:\Work\projects\POCs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:663:20)
    at _err0 (eval at create (D:\Work\projects\POCs\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at Array.compiler.inputFileSystem.readFile (D:\Work\projects\POCs\node_modules\webpack\lib\DllReferencePlugin.js:54:24)
    at Storage.finished (D:\Work\projects\POCs\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at ReadFileContext.provider (D:\Work\projects\POCs\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9)
    at ReadFileContext.callback (D:\Work\projects\POCs\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:115:16)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:237:13)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! POCs@1.0.0 storybook: `start-storybook -p 6006`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the POCs@1.0.0 storybook script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Any help on what might be going wrong? It used to run like this before.

Comment: Thanks for the break. I learned how to manually install storybook of an older release version. There is always a positive learning from a failure.

Answer (score 3):

There an issue report on Github: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/9749

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Happy to know that I am not the only one :p. How do I then downgrade it to 5.3.10 as others have mentioned? npx -p @storybook/cli@5.3.10 sb init didn't work

Comment: Manually changed the version in the devDependencies and installed and it worked.